# Бот не отвечает на кодовые слова

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot, обработка-данных

Делаю бота, который должен отправлять картинку по кодовому слову, к примеру:

**бот**, скинь картинку с **собачками**

Вот мой код :

```py
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_photo(message):
    words = "бот картинку картинка картины".split()
    dogs = "собак собака собаки собаку собачками".split()
    plac = "пейзажи пейзаж пейзажем".split()
    space = "космос космосом".split()
    if message.text.lower() in words:
        if message.text.lower() in dogs and words:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"* картинка с собакой *")
        elif message.text.lower() in plac:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"* картинка с пейзажем *")
        elif message.text.lower() in space:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"* картинка с космосом *")
    #else:
        #bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"не было введено кодового слова")
```

Не понимаю, почему оно ничего не выводит? Ведь после того, как идет проверка на ключевое слово **бот** или **картинка**, должна быть проверка на тему картинки и, если слово, к примеру, собака, то кидать фото из группы собак?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в `message.text` будет строка `"бот, скинь картинку с собачками"` и по коду вы пытаетесь **всю эту строку** найти как элемент списка `words`.

А по факту, нужно наоборот -- разделять `message.text` на слова и эти слова искать в `words` и `dogs`. Анализ слов запрос позволит понять **намерения** пользователя.

Накидал простенький пример анализа слов запроса. В качестве токенизатора использовал регулярку. *Но можно использовать полноценный токенизатор и кроме вытаскивания слов, убрать ненужные токены, а слова, например привести в начальную форму.*

Пример:

```
import re
...


    
    words = "бот картинку картинка картины".split()
    dogs = "собак собака собаки собаку собачками".split()
    plac = "пейзажи пейзаж пейзажем".split()
    space = "космос космосом".split()

    text = message.text.lower()
    tokens = re.findall(r'\w+', text)
    
    # Если в запросе есть слово из words
    if any(x in words for x in tokens):
        # Если в запросе есть слово из dogs
        if any(x in dogs for x in tokens):
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "* картинка с собакой *")

        elif any(x in plac for x in tokens):
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "* картинка с пейзажем *")

        elif any(x in space for x in tokens):
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "* картинка с космосом *")
```

Можно сделать без токенизации, тогда, проверка немного меняется -- ключевые слова ищутся в тексте запроса (но нужно внимательнее слова подбирать, т.к. тут поиск будет по подстроке в тексте запроса):

```
    text = message.text.lower()

    if any(x in text for x in words):
        if any(x in text for x in dogs):
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "* картинка с собакой *")

        elif any(x in text for x in plac):
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "* картинка с пейзажем *")

        elif any(x in text for x in space):
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "* картинка с космосом *")
```

Comment: спасибо,можете поподробнее обьяснить про то как это работает if any(x in text for x in words):
        if any(x in text for x in dogs):
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "* картинка с собакой *")

        elif any(x in text for x in plac):
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "* картинка с пейзажем *")

        elif any(x in text for x in space):
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "* картинка с космосом *")

Comment: @BELEЦKIY, пожалуйста :) `any` эта функция, что принимает коллекцию и возвращает True, если хотя бы один ее элемент вернул `True`. Т.е. мы сделали генератор в нем перебираются элементы `words` (`for x in words`) и проверяется если ли элемент из `words` в `text`. Если есть, то `any` сразу вернет `True`, иначе будет перебор всех элементов `words` и вернется `False` если не нашлось. Это `any(x in text for x in words)` можно представить как `items = [x in text for x in words]` `any(items)`, если выведите `items` увидите на каком слове было найдено соответствие

Comment: огромное спасибо  :))