# Как сделать так чтоб бот реагировал на слова,которые есть в сообщении? (Python TeleBot)

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Пример:
Рандомное сообщения , **слово**

Сообщения бота: В вашем сообщение есть: **слово**

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1229356/201445

Answer (score 0):

Все просто. В ботах я не разбираюсь, правда но поиск слов я знаю.

```
string = 'hello:  gg, hh,word'
for repl in ';:,./\|&*()!@#$%^-+`~':
    string = string.replace(repl, ' ')
data = set(map(str.upper, string.split()))
keyword = 'WORD'
if keyword in data:
    print('В вашем предложении есть слово:', keyword.lower())
```